# Using xCode in a .net application

Tags: .net, xcode

I have a mac application(written with xcode) i have to write a .net application that uses this code. what is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Could you provide more details about your scenario? What are those applications supposed to do?

Comment: I have a mac application that i have to rewrite as a asp .net application, i don't want to rewrite the core code(the algorithm)  so i want to wrap it with a .net managed interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in objective-c, then you should probably try to get it working with [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/), not .NET.

If you absolutely need .NET.  Use the GNU objective-c compiler to make .lib files for as much as possible and then I guess rewrite the GUI in .NET.  Wrap the .lib in a C++/CLI assembly with managed interfaces that you can call from your .NET application.